# Are LASSO regression predicted values also biased?

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, lasso, bias

Since LASSO regression biases coefficients to reduce variance, aren't the predicted values also biased?

In my case I am looking at fitted values from a predictive logistic regression model with LASSO penalty. The distribution of predicted probabilities appears shifted toward zero. I think that if these values are bias, which I think they are, it is okay since these are the predicted values from the model that minimize the misclassification error -- so even though they aren't true predicted values they are the ones that correspond to the "best" model.

I keep scratching my head over this.  o_O

Comment: I know it goes against spirit of site just to post a link, but...http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/steyerberg-application.pdf. "Application of Shrinkage Techniques in Logistic Regression Analysis: A Case Study". I would expect LASSO to improve calibration

Comment: biased coefficiencts--> reduced variance --> better probabilities / calibration on test set (I might avoid thinking of misclassification error with probabilistic model)

Comment: @charles thanks for the paper it is very helpful. Instead of misclassification error what would you use?

Comment: Brier score/scaled Brier, or c-statistic +/- some measure of calibration. The misclassification is useful, but requires one to explicitly state the cost function (False negatives/false positives) and thus derive the optimal probability cut-off (where the cost function is tangent to the ROC). If FN=FP it is just the point where Youden Index maximized (the ROC curve closest to left upper corner, tangent to the line with gradient 1). `@Frank Harrell` has many posts regarding proper scoring rules on this site- and limitations of misclassification as a metric.....

Comment: ... since I'm in the biomedical field this is well accepted. I don't understand what proper scoring rules are (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score) but get the intuitive idea that the model naturally outputs probabilities and treating it like it produces binary classification might produce suboptimal results

Comment: http://www.epibiostat.ucsf.edu/courses/RoadmapK12/SIGS/Steyerberg_Epidemiol_2010.pdf

Comment: @charles very helpful -- I will need to look to see how to optimize the penalty to these measures